# How can i collect specific words in a sentences on Python?

Tags: python

I have a question as i write on title. I'll explain it with examples.

There is a txt file which is looks like,

> This offense was closed with reason: Non-Issue.  Notes: There is no
>   suspicious situation. u0t9231 21 Mar 2018 10:38:46
>
> This offense was closed with reason: Non-Issue.  Notes: Expected
>   traffic. u0t9231 21 Mar 2018 14:20:11

I want to read that txt file and I want to write to another file that will contain just part of "Notes: There is no suspicious situation."

**So input**,

*This offense was closed with reason: Non-Issue.  Notes: There is no suspicious situation. u0t9231 21 Mar 2018 10:38:46"*

**Output**,

```
Notes: There is no suspicious situation
```

Comment: [How to aks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Aren't you already looking for what you already have in the second file. I don't understand the use case; you can just read the second file instead.

Comment: PS. If you want a file which contains only "Notes: There is no suspicious situation" then just create that file with this text in it. You don't need any input file for that.

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: You'll have to explain in detail why "Notes: There is no suspicious situation" is the output you want to get. In the title you say you want to "collect specific words", but this looks more like you're searching for sentences that _contain_ specific words. It's unclear what your code is supposed to do. You also haven't posted any code - we expect help-seekers to at least make an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split but that will only work for a single character delimeter. Using regular expressions lets you use words rather than delimeters to be more specific about words you're looking for.

```
import re

line='This offense was closed with reason: Non-Issue. Notes: There is no suspicious situation. u0t9231 21 Mar 2018 10:38:46'

found = re.search('Notes:.*', line)
print found.group(0)
```

Output:
Notes: Expected traffic. u0t9231 21 Mar 2018 14:20:11

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is divide it into sentences. This can be done by splitting the string into a list by splitting at full stops. If you just want the notes section, then perform an iterative search through the sentences you have just split looking for the keyword "notes"

```
def get_key_sentence(text):
    sentences = text.split(".")
    for sentence in sentences:
        if "notes" in sentence.lower():
            return sentence
```

This function will be able to evaluate a given sentence and then return the needed information.